# pyBarcode - imageWriter settings

Tags: python, python-2.7, barcode, code128

I am using pyBarcode and Python 2.7 to make code128 barcodes. This code successfully make barcodes but with default and i am not ably to figure out how to change it. Thes options parameters does not change anything. Thanks

```
    def createBarcode(self,mac,saveas):
    # Create new instance
    try:
        ean = barcode.get('code128', mac, writer=ImageWriter())
        ean.default_writer_options['module_width'] = 0.2
        ean.default_writer_options['module_height'] = 11
        ean.default_writer_options['quit_zone'] = 1
        ean.default_writer_options['text_distance'] = 2
        filename = ean.save(saveas)
```

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this?